# How to automatically capture photos using an android app in every n seconds

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I am trying to make an android app that captures photos after every 5 seconds. Currently the technique i'm using, uses the phone's camera app to capture the photo. It requires the user to capture the photo and then to press ok and only after that the control returns back to the android app. I found some codes to do the same without human interaction, but since i'm new to android, i'm not able to understand codes them because most of them are incomplete and divided into multiple activities. Can this be done using just one activity?

EDIT : 
The codes mentioned above can be found [here](http://chandandroid.blogspot.in/2014/04/capturing-image-without-user-action.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to use this [library](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) (here [documentation](https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/)) instead the official Camera Api of Android that could be really tricky to use for beginners

Then your code could be like this

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(); //This should be declared before OnCreate
private Runnable photoRunnable; //This also

CameraView camera = findViewById(R.id.camera);

camera.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {

    public void onPictureTaken(PictureResult result) {
        //Handle result here!
    }

});


photoRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    camera.takePicture(); //The result will be in onPictureTaken
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Handle Exception!
                }
                finally{
                    //also call the same runnable to call it at regular interval
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10*1000); //10*1000 is your interval (in this case 10 seconds)
                }
            }
        };

        //runnable must be execute once
        handler.post(photoRunnable);
```

Remember to manage the **lifecycle of handler**